# SQLServer Physical Log shrinking automatically with AutoShrink off

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, shrink

Running in SQLServer 2016 I have a weird situation where the Physical log is shrinking without any interaction and with AutoShrink=false set.

Also, on occasion the size is shrinking below the initial size set in the options for the db.

Seems to be happening to 5 out of 30 databases on this setup.

No agent jobs set to shrink either.

Really at a loss here as to how this is happening. Any ideas?

Snapshots have been used to restore in the past.

The behaviour is being observed using `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)`, which is run at regular intervals throughout the day.